# Derived tensor product and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Apologies for the naive question. Let $X$ be a projective variety over a field, and let  $F^\bullet$ be an object in $D^b(X):= D^b_{coh}(\operatorname{Qcoh}X)$. Suppose now that $E$ is an object complex in $D^b(X)$; I would like to know when $H^i(F^\bullet \otimes^L E) \cong H^i(F^\bullet) \otimes E$.

Certainly if $i$ is the maximal integer such that $H^i(F^\bullet) \neq 0$ the formula holds by right exactness of the tensor product, but say if $F^\bullet$ belongs to $\operatorname{Perf} X$, is this true for all $i$?

Comment: I don't understand, the left-hand side seems to be a coherent sheaf whereas the right-hand side a complex. Don't you want $E$ a coherent sheaf ? Even this you need some flatness hypothesis...

Comment: Yea sorry the right side shouldn't be a derived tensor. I assumed in the question that $E$ is a coherent sheaf. My question is asking if some version of this is true with a flatness assumption only on $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $E$ to be flat. For an example that doesn't work if $E$ is not flat, take $X=\mathbb P^1$ and $F^\bullet=E=\mathcal O_p[0]$, the structure sheaf of a point  concentrated in degree $0$. Since they both supported at a point, we can do this computation on an affine neighborhood of it. For example, let $p=0\in \mathbb A^1$, so that $\mathcal O_p=\frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}$.

We can resolve $E$ by flat sheaves as the complex
$$
E\overset{\operatorname{qiso}}\cong \left(k[t]\overset{t}\longrightarrow k[t]\right).
$$
Then $F^\bullet\otimes^L E$ is given by tensoring this resolution by $F=\frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}$, so we get the complex
$$
F^\bullet\otimes^L E\overset{\operatorname{qiso}}\cong\left(\frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}\overset{t}\longrightarrow \frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}\right)=\left(\frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}\overset{0}\longrightarrow \frac{k[t]}{tk[t]}\right).
$$
Now, we can see that
$$
H^{-1}(F^\bullet\otimes^L E) \cong \frac{k[t]}{tk[t]} \not\cong 0 =H^{-1}(F^\bullet)\otimes E.
$$